# How to correctly write the contents of a Byte array to a file in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I have a variable declaration as follows -

```
Public CA() As Byte
```

When I want to write the contents of this to a file, I do the following -

```
myStr = StrConv(CA, vbUnicode)        
intFileHandle = FreeFile
Open "myFile.txt" For Output As #intFileHandle
Print #intFileHandle, myStr
Close #intFileHandle
```

However, I am not sure whether this is the correct way. Could you recommend a correct way to write the contents of the byte array to the file?

Comment: You loop through the contents of the `Byte` array in the same order you read them.

Answer (score 4):

```
dim fnum As Integer
fnum = FreeFile()
Open "myFile.txt" For Binary As #fnum
Put #fnum, 1, CA
Close fnum
```

Comment: When I try this, program crashes on the first line, Compile error: Can't find project or library.

Comment: @Essej Start a new VB project, open References and see what is activated there. I think in your crashing project, misses references to the VB runtimes.